# Removing object from Array

Tags: arrays, swift

How can you remove a specific object from an Array of string.

```
array = ["mac","iPhone","iPad"]
```

Is there a method to delete a specific string in the array, like for example i wanted to remove "iPhone", without using removeAtIndex(1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use filter for that purpose

```
var array = ["mac","iPhone","iPad"]
array = array.filter() { $0 != "mac" }
print(array) // will print ["iPhone", "iPad"]
```